# Meaning of predValue field in H2O Random forest model

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, random-forest, decision-tree, h2o

I built an `H2ORandomForestEstimator` model using `train()` method on my spark dataframe with the target column containing values 0 or 1. I downloaded and printed its mojo files using `model.download_mojo(MOJO_ZIP_PATH)` and `h2o.print_mojo(MOJO_ZIP_PATH, tree_index=tree_ind)` functions respectively. A partial such output tree is shown below.

As can be seen, leaf nodes have a field named `predValue` containing a value between 0 and 1. What is the meaning of this `predValue` field? Does it mean that the target variable is likely to contain the value contained in `predValue` field if the input variables happen to meet this root to leaf path when `predict()` is called on them?

Moreover, I want to preprocess the output model of `H2ORandomForestEstimator` and filter only those rules (root to leaf paths) for which my model will predict 1. Is there a way to filter such rules by parsing the mojo files without actually running the `predict()` function on input variables? `predValue` field in the output mojo files looked promising to solve this problem but I could not figure out its co-relation with the output variable. Can it be used to figure out the top-N rules?

```
'trees': [{
    'root': {
        'nodeNumber': 0,
        'weight': 18319.0,
        'colId': 169,
        'colName': 'pkg_items_gl_product_group_desc_1.gl_electronics',
        'leftward': True,
        'isCategorical': False,
        'inclusiveNa': True,
        'splitValue': 0.5,
        'rightChild': {
            'nodeNumber': 25,
            'weight': 462.0,
            'predValue': 0.9935065
        },
        'leftChild': {
            'nodeNumber': 1,
            'weight': 17857.0,
            'colId': 0,
            'colName': 'pkg_attr_total_pkg_price',
            'leftward': True,
            'isCategorical': False,
            'inclusiveNa': True,
            'splitValue': 186.52805,
            'rightChild': {
                'nodeNumber': 26,
                'weight': 201.0,
                'predValue': 0.9900498
            },
            'leftChild': {
                'nodeNumber': 3,
                'weight': 13184.0,
                'colId': 149,
                'colName': 'pkg_items_gl_product_group_desc_1.gl_automotive',
                'leftward': True,
                'isCategorical': False,
                'inclusiveNa': True,
                'splitValue': 0.5,
                'rightChild': {
                    'nodeNumber': 27,
                    'weight': 312.0,
                    'predValue': 0.99038464
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question.

Every leaf node contains `predValue` = information regarding the final prediction made on that node.

See tree structure info here:

- Python: https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/tree.html
- R: https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/H2OTree-class.html

To get information if the result prediction is 0 or 1, you must get the threshold (`default_threshold`) used for these decisions. You can find the `default_threshold` in the model info.

You can get the decision path for the concrete node see `decision_paths` or decision paths for the whole tree, see `tree_decision_path`.

If you are interested in leaf node assignment, see https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html?#predicting-leaf-node-assignment.

Let me know if you have another question.